# Hide a specific Div which have no class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the **specific div**(Example 2) but it has no class or id so i am unable to apply jquery on that specific div(Example 2)...Please guide me how can hide that div with jquery.

Here is my div structure:

```
<div class="purhist-desc-col">
  <h5>Heading Sample</h5>
  <div class="purchase-price"></div>
  <div>Example 1</div>
  <div class="booking-hide-on-wholeday">00:00 Check-out 00:00</div>
  <div>Example 2</div>
  <div>Example 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And why jQuery if we can do it easily with CSS :

```css
.purhist-desc-col>div:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
/* OR
booking-hide-on-wholeday + div {
  display: none;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="purhist-desc-col">
  <h5>Heading Sample</h5>
  <div class="purchase-price"></div>
  <div>Example 1</div>
  <div class="booking-hide-on-wholeday">00:00 Check-out 00:00</div>
  <div>Example 2</div>
  <div>Example 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: and if example is the second last child of the main div....how can i do this with css ?

Comment: @ma123456 i added more example ;) you can use nth-child

Comment: Thanks alot...u saved my time

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOM relationship and target the desired element using its siblings.

```js
$('.booking-hide-on-wholeday').next().hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purhist-desc-col">
  <h5>Heading Sample</h5>
  <div class="purchase-price"></div>
  <div>Example 1</div>
  <div class="booking-hide-on-wholeday">00:00 Check-out 00:00</div>
  <div>Example 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to use `.next` - you can use the CSS next-sibling selector in the jquery selector like this: `$('.booking-hide-on-wholeday + div')`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by `+` (next) selector.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('.booking-hide-on-wholeday + div').hide();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purhist-desc-col">
<h5>Heading Sample</h5>
<div class="purchase-price"></div>
<div>Example 1</div>
<div class="booking-hide-on-wholeday">00:00 Check-out 00:00</div>
<div>Example 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

You could select that div with `.purhist-desc-col div:last-of-type` since you need to target the last div inside that container so the jQuery code would be

```
$('.purhist-desc-col div:last-of-type').hide()
```

and in *vanillaJS*

```
document.querySelector('.purhist-desc-col div:last-of-type').style.display = 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to write a lineer jquery code for it.

```
$('div.booking-hide-on-wholeday').next('div').hide();
```

That will solve your question.

Thanks